# Category in a coend depends on the integration variable of an outer coend

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\mathsf{Finj}$ be a skeleton of the category of finite sets and injections. Let $n$ denote its typical object, and as usual $n/\mathsf{Finj}$ the coslice category at $n \in \mathsf{Finj}$. So, an object in $n/FInj$ is a pair $(m, f : n\to m)$. Finally, let $A$ be a set and $A^\bullet : \mathsf{Finj}° \to \mathsf{Set}$ be the functor $n\mapsto A^n$.

Now. I've been told that the following functor is the object part of a monad on $[\mathsf{Finj},\mathsf{Set}]$:
$$
TX : n \mapsto \left(\int^{(m,f) \in n/\mathsf{Finj}} A^m \times Xm\right)^{A^n}
$$ 
The mate of the initial cowedge yields a candidate unit map. No problem. Multiplication seems quite a bit more painful to find, because if I try to evaluate $TTX$ on $n$, I obtain the scary
$$
\begin{align*}
TTXn &= \left( \int^{m\in n /\mathsf{Finj}} A^m \times \left( \int^{p\in m /\mathsf{Finj}} A^p \times Xp \right)^{A^m} \right)^{A^n}\\
& \to \left(\int^{m \in n/\mathsf{Finj}} \int^{p\in m /\mathsf{Finj}} A^p \times Xp \right)^{A^n}\\
& {\color{red} \to} \left(\int^{p\in m /\mathsf{Finj}} A^p \times Xp \right)^{A^n} \\
& = TXn
\end{align*}
$$ In the first step I used the evaluation map of the cartesian closed structure of $\mathsf{Set}$, but I have no idea why the red map should exist.

The problem is that in the integral 
$$
\int^{m \in n/\mathsf{Finj}} \int^{p\in m /\mathsf{Finj}} A^p \times Xp
$$ the innermost integral depends on the integration variable of the outer one. I must admit my coend-fu is too weak to find how this can be further reduced, and this situation directly leads to the following vague but general question:

> Let $\mathcal I$ be a category, and let $-/\mathcal I : \mathcal I° \to \sf Cat$ be the coslice functor $i\mapsto i/\mathcal I$. How can one evaluate the following?
>   $$
> \int^{i\in k/\mathcal I} \int^{X\in i/\mathcal I} T(X,X)
> $$

Comment: Here's a guess: maybe(?) if $X \to Y$ is bicartesian, then $\mathsf{Tw}(X) \to \mathsf{Tw}(Y)$ is cocartesian (or cartesian, depending on the convention you used to define Tw...) in which case one could compute colimits over $\mathsf{Tw}(X)$ fiberwise. (Applying this to $A\times B \to B$ gives the usual Fubini)

Comment: I'll be glad to read an answer, even if it does not solve the problem, where you explain what you mean precisely by "compute colimits fiberwise": I'm not familiar with the practice.

Comment: In general, if $E \to B$ is a map, then I can compute the colimit over $E$ by left Kan extending to B and then computing the colimit. The value of the left Kan extension at b is the colimit over $E \downarrow b$. When $E \to B$ is cocartesian, the natural map $E_b \to E \downarrow b$ is final, so you may compute the colimit over $E_b$ instead.

Comment: Where by "is cocartesian" I presume you mean "is an opfibration"?  I've seen people call these "cocartesian fibrations" but never simply "cocartesian".

Comment: @MikeShulman Yes, thank you- I was being a bit informal but I see that it might be confusing: I mean "cocartesian fibration" (and "bicartesian fibration" and "cartesian fibration" etc.) in my comments.